# django configure apache to serve media and static files

Tags: python, django, apache

So I have apache and mod-wsgi installed on windows. Now I need to configure apache to serve django's media files.
**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include('api_backend.urls'))
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

apache **conf/httpd.conf**

```py
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/iyapp/pycharmprojects/cloud_server/venv/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win32.pyd"
...
# custom httpd configuration

WSGIPythonPath "c:/users/iyapp/pycharmprojects/cloud_server"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/iyapp/pycharmprojects/cloud_server/venv"

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/users/iyapp/pycharmprojects/cloud_server/rebox_django/wsgi.py"


    Alias /media/ "c:/users/iyapp/pycharmprojects/cloud_server/media/"
    Alias /static/ "c:/users/iyapp/pycharmprojects/cloud_server/static/"

    <Directory "c:/users/iyapp/pycharmprojects/cloud_server/static">
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "c:/users/iyapp/pycharmprojects/cloud_server/media">
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "c:/users/iyapp/pycharmprojects/cloud_server/rebox_django">
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

This is what I have so far. However, when I try to access a media file that the server has, I get a 404 not found error. Why is that? Can someone please help me?

I am using Apache24 (32 bits with python) and the mod-wsgi python module.
**settings.py**

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'rebox_django.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'rebox_django.wsgi.application'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = []
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

Comment: Did you ever get this squared away? I"m having the same issue except on a different OS and in production. Basically did all the things you have done and also included the `'django.template.context_processors.media',` to the OPTIONS in the settings file to no avail.